# select all distinct values from a merge of multiple fields MySql

Tags: mysql, select, merge, distinct

assuming I have a table like this:

```
A     B        C
10    aname    avalue
11    aname    bvalue
11    aname    bvalue
10    bname    avalue
11    cname    bvalue
```

of this set i would like to select all the combinations that i have, for instance:

```
10 aname avalue
11 aname bvalue
10 bname avalue
11 cname bvalue
```

so basically the `SELECT DISTINCT of ( A & B & C )` .
Is that possible, or is better to make a php script to get the values and arrange / group them as i like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a, b, c from t group by a, b, c
```

Answer (score 1):

Or more shot but the same (obviously both generates same plan).

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM tbl
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86765/1)**